# Getting value from different pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Currently I'm developing a mobile application using Xcode 7 Swift. My application use pickerView. I have 7 pickerView.

What I want to do is, to get the value of the every pickerView after press the button. But I don't know how. I'm still beginner in Xcode and Swift.

Here is my coding

```
    @IBOutlet weak var vomit: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headache: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var muscle: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var abdominal: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var skin: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bleeding: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fever: UIPickerView!

    var pickerVomit: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerHead: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerMuscle: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerAbdominal: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerSkin: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerBleeding: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerFever: [String] = [String]()


    var vomitData = []
    var headData = []
    var muscleData = []
    var abdominalData = []
    var skinData = []
    var BleedingData = []
    var feverData = []


    @IBAction func backMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        //let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        //view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        vomitData = ["No","Yes"]
        headData = ["No","Yes"]
        muscleData = ["No","Yes"]
        abdominalData = ["No","Yes"]
        skinData = ["No","Yes"]
        BleedingData = ["No","Yes"]
        feverData = ["No","Yes"]

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return vomitData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 2){
            return headData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 3){
            return muscleData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 4){
            return abdominalData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 5){
            return skinData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 6){
            return BleedingData.count
        }
        else {
            return feverData.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return "\(vomitData[row])"
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 2){
            return "\(headData[row])"
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 3){
            return "\(muscleData[row])"
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 4){
            return "\(abdominalData[row])"
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 5){
            return "\(skinData[row])"
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag == 6){
            return "\(BleedingData[row])"
        }
        else {
            return "\(feverData[row])"
        }

    }
```

I really hope someone can help me get through this. Thank you.

Comment: What is your error? Runtime or compile time? Or does it just not work? Please update the question to make it clerarer!

Comment: @MattiasLindberg Hi, thank you for your comment. Im so sorry due to wrong statement in the question. Actually I don't know how do the logic.

Comment: you can get current/selected pickerView index by it's delegate method selectedRowInComponent. than just got the right value from the array using objectAtIndex.

Comment: like for pickerVomit, NSInteger pickerVomit_currentRow = [pickerVomit selectedRowInComponent:0];  then by getting value from array as [vomitData objectAtIndex:pickerVomit_currentRow]

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati is this from Swift language?

Comment: No , but you can convert it to swift it's too easy.

Comment: like let pickerVomit_currentRow = pickerVomit. selectedRowInComponent(0), then vomitData[pickerVomit_currentRow]

Comment: this coding insert in the action button fuction or in the `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` ?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati ok..thank you..I'll try..anything I'll refer to you..

Comment: `let pickerVomit_currentRow = pickerVomit[selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        
let vom = vomitData.objectAtIndex[pickerVomit_currentRow]` but the still have error...unresolved identifier 'selectecRowInComponent... @SaurabhPrajapati

Comment: It's spelling mistake dear , replace it with "selectedRowInComponent"

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati result still the same...

Comment: sorry to say but it's working perfectly for me dear! try it one more time let row = self. vomit.selectedRowInComponent(0) print("(vomitData[row])")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you have 7 pickerview.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vomit: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var headache: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var muscle: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var abdominal: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var skin: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var bleeding: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var fever: UIPickerView!
```

And 7 array containing values according to pickerview.

```
var vomitData = []
var headData = []
var muscleData = []
var abdominalData = []
var skinData = []
var BleedingData = []
var feverData = []
```

Now, you want value from every picker for selected row when button clicked! so add following code in button action method,

```
let int_Vomit = self.vomit.selectedRowInComponent(0)
print("\(vomitData[row])")
```

continue same for other pickerView's.